# Improve Speed of VBA Cells.Find Loop

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I'm new to writing Macros and would love some help improving the speed on this one.

I have a sheet with 35,000+ rows, and I'm looping through it to find each instance of a value (`OldSKU`), grabbing the `SKUSubset` data associated with it (which has a variable number of rows), and pasting it into a new sheet (`SubsetImporter`) at the first empty row.

Right now, it can take 5 minutes to loop through and find all the instances of a SKU that shows up multiple times.

`OldSKU` will only ever show up in Column B.  Is there a way to improve the speed of this loop? Possibly defining the range that it should search through?

```
Sub UpdateSKU()

Dim OldSKU As Long
Dim NewSKU As Long
Dim SKUSubset As String
Dim SubsetRange As Range
Dim aPlace As Range
Dim bPlace As Range
Dim SubsetPastePlace As Long

OldSKU = Sheets("Rollover Request").Range("A2")
NewSKU = Sheets("Rollover Request").Range("B2")

'UPDATE SUBSET IMPORTER
Sheets("Subset Exporter").Activate

Set aPlace = Cells.Find(What:=OldSKU, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

SKUSubset = Cells.Find(What:=OldSKU, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, -1).Value

Set bPlace = aPlace

Set aPlace = Cells.Find(What:=OldSKU, After:=aPlace, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

Range("A1", Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=SKUSubset
Range(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell), Cells(2, 1)).Copy

SubsetPastePlace = Sheets("Subset Importer").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

Sheets("Subset Importer").Range("A" & SubsetPastePlace).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues,     Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Subset Exporter").Activate
Sheets("Subset Exporter").Range("A2").Select
Sheets("Subset Exporter").ShowAllData

If bPlace.Row < aPlace.Row Then
    Do
        SKUSubset = aPlace.Offset(0, -1).Value

        Range("A1", Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=SKUSubset
        Range(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell), Cells(2, 1)).Copy

        SubsetPastePlace = Sheets("Subset Importer").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

        Sheets("Subset Importer").Range("A" & SubsetPastePlace).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Sheets("Subset Exporter").Activate
        Worksheets("Subset Exporter").ShowAllData

        Set bPlace = aPlace
        Set aPlace = Cells.Find(OldSKU, After:=aPlace, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    Loop Until aPlace.Row < bPlace.Row
End If

End Sub
```

[image: Here's the source data that I'm searching through]

Comment: If you only want to search colB then instead of `Cells.Find()` you can use `Columns(2).Find(...)`  Kind of difficult to follow what you're doing here, so if you could post a screenshot of (part) of your source data that might help.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to apply a filter to you data first then loop the remaining records?

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams, I attached the format of my source data.  Basically I'm finding the SKU in Column B, and then filtering on the Group ID in Column A.

Comment: So how do you determine which rows to copy having found the SKU? All rows directly above with no SKU ?

Comment: Once you find a SKU, offset to the left to get the Group ID, which is then defined as SKUSubset.  Then we filter on SKUSubset to get the rows to copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightly-tested:

```
Sub UpdateSKU()

    Dim OldSKU As Long
    Dim NewSKU As Long
    Dim SKUSubset As String
    Dim SubsetRange As Range
    Dim skuCells As Collection, shtExp As Worksheet, shtImp As Worksheet
    Dim skuCell

    Set shtExp = Sheets("Subset Exporter")
    Set shtImp = Sheets("Subset Importer")

    OldSKU = Sheets("Rollover Request").Range("A2")
    NewSKU = Sheets("Rollover Request").Range("B2")

    Set skuCells = FindAll(shtExp.Columns(2), OldSKU) 'get all instances of SKU

    shtExp.Activate
    For Each skuCell In skuCells

        SKUSubset = skuCell.Offset(0, -1).Value

        shtExp.Range("A1", Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).AutoFilter _
                                   Field:=1, Criteria1:=SKUSubset

        shtExp.Range(shtExp.Cells(2, 1), shtExp.UsedRange. _
                       SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Copy

        shtImp.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial _
           Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False

        shtExp.ShowAllData

    Next skuCell

End Sub

'return a Collection containing all cells with value [findWhat]
Function FindAll(rngToSearch As Range, findWhat As Long) As Collection
Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range, add1 As String
    Set f = rngToSearch.Find(what:=findWhat, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        add1 = f.Address()
        Do While Not f Is Nothing
            rv.Add f
            Set f = rngToSearch.FindNext(after:=f)
            If f.Address = add1 Then Exit Do
        Loop
    End If
    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```